# how to pass logger middleware output data into the mysql tables in golang?

Tags: go

### how do i insert following three parameters output param.method, param.statusCode, param.TimeStamp.Format(time.RFC822) from logger middleware into mysql table?

```
func logger() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return gin.LoggerWithFormatter(func(param gin.LogFormatterParams) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s %d %s \n",
            param.Method,
            param.StatusCode,
            param.TimeStamp.Format(time.RFC822),
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the logic is this, I have not used gin, and the code has not been tested.

The request method, response status code, request completion time, and request processing time are recorded in db.

```golang
func logger(db *sql.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        now := time.Now()
        ctx.Next()
        db.Exec("INSERT INTO tb_logger(method,code,accesstime,handletime) VALUE(?,?,?,?)", ctx.Request.Method, ctx.Writer.Status(), time.Now().Format(time.RFC822), time.Now().Sub(now).String())
    }
}
```